# Powershell Script to make New Task Sequence from another script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a ps script to make a new task sequence with another script that I give a path to.

The problem is that although the script creates a Task, the PowerShell script doesn't initiate as I want to.

```
# Script: Make new Task Scheduele
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -Path 
$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\Repository\rig_monitoring.ps1'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 12am -Once -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 4) -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Days (365 * 20))
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Monitoring" -Description "Monitoring Set-up 4 minute interval" -User "System" -RunLevel Highest
```

Comment: Why do you keep your monitoring script in the downloads folder..?

Comment: First of all, change signal quotes to double in `-Argument`. Otherwise, the path is literally `$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\Repository\rig_monitoring.ps1`

Comment: Of course I mean single quotes

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Tried to get Resolve-Path to look for rig_monitoring.ps1 everywhere but I failed. That would have been great to have it look for the name of the script everywhere and add it no matter the download location.

Comment: @robdy Chaged the wording to the follwoing:    `$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -Argument "& 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Monitoring_Powershell\powershell_monitoring.ps1'"` and it works now as intended. I just wish I was able to locate the .ps1 anywhere no matter the download location.

Comment: @Vido Download location should always be `$HOME\Downloads` unless a user manually changes where they download files.

Comment: "Resolve-Path to look for rig_monitoring.ps1 everywhere", why not just use this: (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Filter 'rig_monitoring.ps1' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName.

Comment: @postanote You sir are a legend. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.  See my update to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for all that helped out.

Final version works perfectly to what I wanted:

## Script: Make new Task Scheduele

```
$location = (get-childitem -Path 'C:\' -Filter 'powershell_monitoring.ps1' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -Argument "-NonInteractive -NoLogo -NoProfile -File $location"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $(Get-Date).AddMinutes(1) -Once -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 4) -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Days (365 * 20))
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "PS Monitoring" -Description "Monitoring Set-up 4 minute interval" -User "System" -RunLevel Highest
```

Answer (score 0):

Original response

> "Resolve-Path to look for rig_monitoring.ps1 everywhere"

why not just use this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Filter 'rig_monitoring.ps1' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName.
```

***Updated response***

Just in case there is more than one drive on the users systems and with the user potentially saving to one of those instead.

```
(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem').Root | 
%{(Get-ChildItem -Path $PSItem -Filter 'rig_monitoring.ps1' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName} | 
Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```